# copy all values from 0ne array to another

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray, nsarray

`identifierListController.nameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:nameArrayT copyItems:YES];`

namearray is array of view controllers.  I am reading values from webserver and putting into nameArrayT and then from nameArrayT to nameArray of the 2nd view which I select from the array.

I have tried:

1. `identifierListController.nameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:nameArrayT copyItems:YES];`
2. `identifierListController.nameArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:nameArrayT];`
3. `[identifierListController.nameArray addObject:soapResults1];`
4. `[identifierListController.nameArray addObjectsFromArray:nameArrayT];`

and all is not working for me, as when i am trying to display values of array by using `NSLog()` its shows `null` .

Do I have to create an NSString object and then copy that to the array?
I hope some one knows how to do this.

Thanks :)

Comment: are you able to print your original array (nameArrayT)??

Comment: What is the property doing?  Have you synthesized getter/setter methods for it?  Did you implement them yourself?  If so, what does the methods look like?

Comment: @lukya "NSLog(@"nameArray : %@",nameArrayT);" values are not there, but something like following coming : nameArrayT : (
    "Automatic CSG selection in E-UTRA with CSG list on USIM, success",
    "Automatic CSG selection in E-UTRA with CSG list on USIM, success",
    "Automatic CSG selection in E-UTRA with CSG list on USIM, success",
    "Automatic CSG selection in E-UTRA with CSG list on USIM, success"

Comment: have u checked  identifierListController is correctly allocated ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try first to allocate the array and then to copy objects:

```
identifierListController.nameArray = [NSMutableArray new];
[identifierListController.nameArray addObjectsFromArray:nameArrayT];
```

Answer (score 1):

i hope you have made propery for name array and synthesized it as well,then you just need to do this.

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *nameArray;
```

and alloc this whether in LoadView,ViewDidLoad as you require.

```
[identifierListController.nameArray addObjectsFromArray:nameArrayT];
```

Or use this

```
NSMutableArray *nameArrayResult= [identifierListController.nameArray addObjectsFromArray:nameArrayT];
```

Now you can access array contents from nameArrayResult.

This will help you
Good luck